# What causes 100Hz spuriour emissions on AD9850 WSPR transmitter?

Tags: rf, radio, ham-radio, dds, ad9850

I've built WSPR transmitter based on AD9850.
AD9850 is driven by 125 MHz crystal. TX frequency is 14 Mhz.
On the receive side there is upconverter (+125 MHZ crystal) and SDR (both RTL-SDR and AirSpy). Both SDRs show the same 100Hz spurious emissions.

What is the source of these emissions? Is it coming from upconverter or from AD9850?

[image]

Comment: powersupply? is mains 50Hz where you are?

Comment: Do you have separate 125 MHz crystals for Tx and Rx?

Comment: Do the spurious sidebands show up when your receivers are tuned to other signals (WWV, etc.)? If so, suspect the up-converter.  Also, check the receive frequency error against WWV, if it's 100 Hz, suspect IMD due to two different slightly offset 125 MHz sources.

Comment: @Jasen Please promote this to answer. Indeed, that was caused by power supply ripple in the power amplifier of the transmitter.

Comment: @hotpaw2 After fixing first issue, I also noticed crystal difference spur, but at lower level. It was very visible when touching one of the crystals. Difference though is very unstable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

100Hz or 120Hz noise is often caused by power-supply ripples or rectifier glitches. those being twice the mains frequency in different locations.